# Prove that if $a+b = y$, where $a \neq 1$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$;$ a^b+b = 1 (\mod y)$ then

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove the following conjecture:

If for two integers $a, b$:

$a+b = y$, $a ≠ 1$, and $\gcd(a, b) =1$

$a^b+b$ $\equiv$ $1$$\pmod y$

$y$ is prime.

(I am new here at math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Which one is the conjecture? $y$ is prime or something else? I did not get your question

Comment: Welcome to Math.Se.  In order to help as best we can, you should provide us with details about what you already know about the problem and what you have attempted so far.  Also, make sure to write your question clearly labeling what is hypothesis and what is conclusion.

Comment: I want to see if $y$ is always prime if the the following congruence $a^b+b$ = $1$ $\mod y$ holds given the conditions above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture is false, here are some counter-examples:

```
a=22    b=3     y=25  = 5^2  
a=62    b=59    y=121 = 11^2
a=12    b=103   y=115 = 5*23
a=136   b=7     y=143 = 11*13
```